# Django - kwargs aren't passed

Tags: python, django

I am writing an app in Django meant to check XML for errors. It parses each line in the XML file, creates an object (from a class called XMLElement) corresponding to that line, checks the line for errors, generates a string detailing the error, then appends it to a list. Here is a code snippet of what it does:

```
try:
        self.string_list = kwargs['tag_string'].replace("<", "").replace(">", "").split()
        print self.string_list
        self.element_name = self.string_list[0]
    except (ValueError, IndexError) as e:
        self.errors.append("XMLElement {0} contains an error:{1}".format(self.element_name, str(e)))
```

Then, after it is done parsing the file, the model class that the functions are called from joins all the errors into one string, then creates an object with that string as a keyworded argument.

```
    print '\n'.join(obj.errors)
    err_obj = Errors(errors='\n'.join(obj.errors))
```

---

```
class Errors(models.Model):
    errors = models.TextField()
```

Whenever I print the error list from the `XMLElement` instance, the error is printed properly. However, when I try to print the error from the error class using `Errors.objects.all()[n].errors` from the django shell, it returns an empty unicode string. Not only that, but instead of saving one error object, it saves multiple, anywhere between 3 and 5. What part of my code could be causing this?

[Gist link to the entire file](https://gist.github.com/TheMetaphorer/a98f81b2cccf93bafb25)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to fix this problem. By doing two things:

The first thing I did was changed the superclass of the `XMLElement` class from `models.Model` to `object`. That fixed the majority of my problem. However, it didn't help fix a problem where multiple objects would be created by the `__init__` function of my `UserFile` class. I solved this by moving the creation of the `Errors` objects from `UserFile.__init__` to a function called `check` in views.py

Answer (score 0):

*Useless answer about the use of save method. It's not it.*

**Update based on your comments:** There are plenty of areas in your code that could be causing this behaviour, mainly it could be because you're overriding `__init__()`. Overriding that method is very discouraged in Django because the framework uses many ways of initialising instances that are not in your control and it also initialises models for many different things. Make your own `create()` class methods if you need to customise instance creation.

Another thing that I saw a lot in your code (and this is more a comment on how you're using the framework than anything else) was that you're using the Model superclass very lightly on things that you aren't really persisting, like your `XMLElement` class: returning upon initialisation can create a lot of issues with the framework.

My solution for you would be that you should check your algorithm's behaviour outside the framework and then decide what you need to persist and what is just taking up space on your database, then wrap your code on Django classes and for your own sake, stop overriding (and most of all, creating other objects in some other object's) init method.

Comment: are you sure? you're not calling it on your gist, line 56, 57

Comment: I removed it for debugging purposes, I must have not put it in the gist. Even so, putting it back in the code doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: I was able to fix the problem of not passing kwargs by changing the superclass of `XMLElement` from `models.Model` to `object`.  However, this didn't fix the problem of it creating multiple `Errors` objects.